# Connection to database lost after several hours in Grails war

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat, grails, webdeploy

I'm having a rare issue with a war I deployed, and it's connection to the database server (MySQL), here's the thing: 
I made the tomcat config like this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/gimnasioBackend" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSour$
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username=["username"] password=["password"] driverClassName="com$
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/[databaseName]"/>
```

And is connecting just fine, but the thing is that every day I come to check the server status, and also test the pages in it, I can't login. If I restart the server (which is not recommended, judging what I've red), I can login (using spring security) again, but not for long... The situation is complicated, mainly because it's already in production, and is holding a backend for an app.. 
Thanks in advance!

**Note:** There's more than one web app in this tomcat, all of them working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with grails DataSource and with tomcat resource configuration connecting to an Oracle database and I resolved adding

```
validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
validationQueryTimeout=3
validationInterval=15000
```

If the problem is due to connection against database lost I suppose you can try adding those properties. Validation query for mysql should be `select 1` instead of `select 1 from dual`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Gonna check it out.
The funniest thing about it is that locally there's no issue..

Comment: My problem was only in production too because of idle connection being closed by firewall between webserver and database. With that properties, connections are tested before using them and recreated if needed

Comment: Great dude. Thanks, gonna try it later today!